# problems about importing caffe

Tags: python, caffe

when I import caffe,it got some errors:

```
import caffe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lili/caffe/1master/caffe-master/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
  File "/home/lili/caffe/1master/caffe-master/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 15, in <module>
    import caffe.io
  File "/home/lili/caffe/1master/caffe-master/python/caffe/io.py", line 8, in <module>
    from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
  File "/home/lili/caffe/1master/caffe-master/python/caffe/proto/caffe_pb2.py", line 23, in <module>
    \x06\x66iller\x18\x01 \x01(\x0b\x32\x16.caffe.FillerParameter\x12\x1d\n\x0e\x63hannel_shared\x18\x02 \x01(\x08:\x05\x66\x61lse*\x1c\n\x05Phase\x12\t\n\x05TRAIN\x10\x00\x12\x08\n\x04TEST\x10\x01')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'syntax
```

who can help me?

Comment: improved formatting and explanation

Comment: Check this link: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2092

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some problem with the model prototype or the solver prototype you are using for training. Please make sure that the prototype files have only the defined attributes.

Answer (score -1):

check your version of protobuf, it seems the version of protoc and python protobuf do not match